# What's it called when a character mentions something, and the scene immediately cuts to that thing?

Tags: film-techniques

What's it called when a character mentions something, and the scene immediately cuts to that thing?

For example, in *Game of Thrones* Season 4 Episode 4, when

> Littlefinger mentions that his new friends killed Joffrey, a jump cut follows onto Olenna.

Another example is the *Attack on Titan* anime, in episode 2x12 around 13 minutes in, where

> Ymir says, that there is still hope inside the walls and a cut captures Historia. (The viewer didn't know back then, that she's a special character)

This cut appears very often where a character in the scene mentions another character or an action, and the camera cuts to these characters or that action.

What is this cutting or storytelling technique called?

Comment: editing........

Comment: I was thinking it could be "Match Cut", but that's only for visual effects. @JasonPSallinger Not sure if you understood the question or are taking it seriously.

Comment: similar to https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AnswerCut

Comment: @Anatoly the linked trope above is exactly why I am serious.  While you could have specifically named cuts, what you are mentioning is how nearly every single cut is made in any good movie or TV show.  In fact, it is bad editing that puts two scenes together which are not related.

Comment: I thought they meant more like one person going on and on about how thy won't go somewhere/do something and CUT to them going to that somewhere/doing that thing. There was a particularly bad one in Lake Placid, IIRC.

Comment: @JasonPSallinger I see. Then to be more clearer, is it still an Answer Cut if the viewer doesn't know it is an answer cut until later?

Comment: I don't know if there is a name for what you are looking for.  To be honest I was being somewhat facetious.  Editing is what I would call it.

Comment: I see, thank you. I'm just working on my school seminar and was looking if there's a particular name for that.

Comment: @JasonPSallinger I'm not sure if that is always true--sometimes the point of certian scenes being paired together is about misdirection and not always direction. Anatoly is being pretty specific about talking about a character and then cutting to them--I'm not saying it isn't common, but not every scene talks about one character and then immediately jumps to it. I saw no Jango Fett in S2 of the Mandalorian and he was brought up a couple of times by Boba. Is that bad editing, or actually giving Star Wars fans some benefit of the doubt that we already know who that is and what he looks like? :p

Comment: @DarthLocke  Points taken.  Of course not all cuts will be paired.  And there may be some esoteric name for this sequence.  Answer Cut may be it.  But editing is what I would call it.

Comment: But Answer Cut explicitly requires a Question to be asked? Or does it support a more broad definition where it's basically cut towards the mentioned topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[KitKat](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/53462/kitkat) mentioned [Answer Cut](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AnswerCut), which TVTropes describes as:

> When a character asks a question, and the work cuts, pans, or otherwise shifts to an image of the implied answer. This comes in a couple of flavors:
>
> - A direct question followed by a cut to the answer. (e.g., A character asks "who could have done such a thing?" before the shot cuts to the culprit.)
> - A character makes a significant remark (e.g., "Some people just naturally make fools of themselves"), then the camera cuts to another character doing exactly that sort of thing.
> - Another character, completely uninvolved with the initial conversation, answers the question with a line identifying the answer ("What kind of loser takes a job at Burger Fool?" "Hey, did your brother tell you he got a new job?").

I have not seen Attack on Titan but I believe the Game of Thrones examples does list your prompt:

> In "Oathkeeper", Littlefinger talks about his new allies and a friendship "growing strong", then we cut to Margaery and Olenna strolling the gardens.

Comment: The original mention of the [Answer Cut](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/116197/whats-it-called-when-a-character-mentions-something-and-the-scene-immediately/121870#comment200548_116197) goes to KitKat, thanks to them!

Comment: Ah, I guess I had not uncollapsed the comments when I first saw this, will update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Initially, I would have said the cutaway since it is supposed to parallel the lines of action and guide the audience to a subtle conclusion (even foreshadowing which they call Chekov's Gun). In terms of writing its called [lampshading](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LampshadeHanging), that I know for a fact - it is well used in fiction[.](https://www.slaphappylarry.com/what-is-lampshading/) There probably is a very specific term for it, but my textbook doesn't have a name  other than a [cutaway](https://shootsta.com/blog/how-to-master-the-art-of-cutaway-shots/#:%7E:text=For%20a%20cutaway%20definition%2C%20cutaways,back%20to%20the%20main%20shot.) and a lengthy explanation at how transitions work. Editing consists mostly of match cuts, jump cuts, j and l cuts, montage, and cutting on action, because it all has to flow with the plot. Direct storytelling is another way to describe that. Hope that helped a bit.

Edit: Just noticed in the comments someone mentioned Answer Cut and now I look like a fool :)
Added links to help explain some terms

Comment: Maybe lampshading is what I might look for if I understand it correctly. Is it something similar like the Answer Cut?

Comment: @GalacticNebula interesting answer, but I think it would benefit if you could provide some credible links to either lampshading and/or cutaway.